# Run Time Error Generated when opening Microsoft Word Document from Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

Receiving a Runtime Error '13' exception when creating a word application object.  I also was experiencing relatively extreme delays (on the order of 20-30 seconds) of running prior to the exception. Any idea what this could be from?  I searched Stackoverflow and I haven't seen anything that was very similar.

I have never worked with an word doc from excel before so this is something new to me.

Code Below:

```
Public Sub GetRawData()
    'Meant to translate data from a raw word file and format into excel
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim objWord As Application

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document

    'File management vars
    Dim oneLine As Paragraph
    Dim lineText As String
    filePath = "U:\Research_Dev Docs\DevFolder\Word Doc Translation In Excel For Phys\testWordDoc.docx"

    'Set word doc object using standard file directory and file name
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(Filename:=filePath, Visible:=True)

    For Each oneLine In objDoc.Paragraphs
        'Pull in each line and eventually parse
        lineText = oneLine.Range.Text

        'DEBUG OUTPUT TO THE SCREEN FOR TESTING
        MsgBox (lineText)

    Next oneLine

End Sub
```

Comment: Change your declaration to `Dim objWord As Word.Application`. As is, VBA assumes you mean `Excel.Application` which gives a type mis-match (Error 13). You'll also need a reference to the Microsoft Word x.x Object Library.

Comment: @xidgel I'll give that a try now.  I have the object library enabled